# .mo translation strings not loading in PHP scripts that handle AJAX calls

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, hooks, translation, textdomain

using the standard `__('some-string', 'myplugin')` for translations, strings are being correctly loaded for a Japanese (ja) locale in every function and script other than my AJAX functions.

**my-plugin.php:**

```
*Text Domain: myplugin
*Domain Path: /languages/
*/
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );
function myplugin_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 
}
require_once(basename( dirname( __FILE__)."/classes/myplugin_handler.class.php");
global $myplugin_handler;
$myplugin_handler = new myplugin_handler();
```

**myplugin_handler.class.php:**

```
class myplugin_handler
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_ajax_myplugin_ajax', array($this, 'myplugin_ajax_handler'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myplugin_ajax', array($this, 'myplugin_ajax_handler'));
    }

    public function myplugin_ajax_handler() {
        if ($_POST['action'] != 'myplugin_ajax') {
            wp_die(0);
        }
        if (!check_ajax_referer('myplugin-ajax-nonce', 'security')) {
            wp_die(0);
        }

        $closemsg = __('Close', 'myplugin');
        wp_die($closemsg);
    }
}
```

*Close* should translate to *閉じる* but it does not. Where translation does work:

- plugin function calls from the theme
- plugin function calls from an admin screen
- `_e()` and `__()` calls in embedded js in the footer
- seemingly everywhere else besides AJAX functions

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a typo in the text domain for every call in my ajax function. For examples sake I entered the text domain as 'myplugin' in my question, but the real text domain is 'asumil-wishlist'. Instead of a hyphen I accidentally put an underscore, so `__('somestring', 'asumil-wishlist')` was `__('somestring', 'asumil_wishlist')`.

Thanks anyways for the suggestions everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to load the translations earlier to make them available for ajax hooks:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );
function myplugin_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'myplugin', false, basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip but I should have clarified that I tried that hook, as well as `after_setup_theme` and neither of them resolved the problem

Comment: It works here, I can not see any other problem in your code, so maybe the problem is anywhere else in you code base.